# Effect of visual studio compiler settings on performance of CUDA kernels

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, compiler-optimization

I get about 3-4x times difference in computation time of a same CUDA kernel compiled on two different machines. Both versions run on a same machine and GPU device. The direct conclusion explaining the difference is different compiler settings. Although there is no single perfect setting and the tuning should be customized depending on the kernel, I wonder if there is any clear guideline for helping to choose the right settings. I use Visual Studio 2010. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Compile in release mode, not debug mode, if you want fastest performance.  The `-G` switch passed to the nvcc compiler will usually have a negative effect on GPU code performance.
2. It's generally recommended to select the right architecture for the GPU you are compiling for.  For example, if you have a cc 2.1 capability GPU, make sure that setting (sm_21, in GPU code settings) is being passed to the compiler.  There are some counter examples to this (e.g. compiling for cc 2.0 seems to run faster, etc.) but as a general recommendation, it is best.
3. Use the latest version of CUDA (compiler).  This is especially important when using GPU libraries (CUFFT, CUBLAS, etc.) (yes, this is not really a compiler setting)

Comment: Although obvious, I would also say that compiler optimizations matter (`O1`, `O2`, ...) :-)

Comment: I agree, although I think this is mostly a host compiler flag, and the question seems to be asking about the performance of a CUDA kernel.  In my limited testing, I have not seen significant differences in ptx code generation going from `-O0` to `-O3`, although I'd certainly be interested to be proven wrong.  If we're talking about host compiler optimizations for VS code, probably there are many others as well.

Comment: @RobertCrovella.  The -G flag made a massive difference in execution time for my kernels.  I did not change the optimization level O1, O2, etc.